# Why ballerina doesn't provide a base64 encoding and decoding but only provide base64URL encoding and decoding

Tags: ballerina

I have noticed that ballerina encoding package doesn't have method for encodeBase64/decodeBase64 but rather have encodeBase64URL/decodeBase64URL.

when I am using this and working with other base64 encoding libraries, the results are not same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base64 encode [1] and base64 URL encode [2] are different. Ballerina provides base64 encoding/decoding APIs from language itself. You can use `ballerina/encoding` module for base64 URL encoding/decoding.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string input = "Hello Ballerina!";
    byte[] inputArr = input.toBytes();
    string encodedString = inputArr.toBase64();
    io:println(encodedString);
}
```

Please refer the crypto BBE [3] for more examples.

[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4

[2] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5

[3] https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/crypto.html

---

**[UPDATE]** Sample for base64 encode/decode.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/lang.'array as arr;
import ballerina/lang.'string as str;

public function main() returns error? {
    string input = "Hello Ballerina!";
    byte[] inputArr = input.toBytes();
    string encodedString = inputArr.toBase64();
    io:println(encodedString);

    byte[] decoded = check arr:fromBase64(encodedString);
    string decodedString = check str:fromBytes(decoded);
    io:println(decodedString);
}
```

Comment: @idclakmal, Thanks, does the language provide the decoding from base64 as well? I wasn't able to find any method to decode base64 encoded string to byte array

Comment: @Mayuran yes. Please refer to the updated example of the answer.

Comment: @idclakmal, Thanks much, I was looking around all apis(string, encoding) but dint check array :(